# What is the difference between saving my API Key in secret manager and hardcoding it in a cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-secret-manager

I am trying to combine OpenAI with my Flutter app, during my research I found out that I can save apikey in secret manager and request from my cloud function for my firebase as server, but I don't know the difference if I just hardcode apikey in cloud function, and trigger this in my flutter app, user can still not get my apikey, and secret manager costs and takes time.

What are the benefits of using the secret manager?

Comment: The most obvious reason is that a hard coded key is sitting in source code and anyone that can access your source code can now use that key. Remember your source code might be in Git, on your local hard drive, might get backed up somewhere. Its very easy to "leak" secrets this way. Even if you clear your secret out, it can exist in a prior version in Git

Comment: Browse the OpenAI community chat, look at all the people that are stuck with large bills because someone got their key during transmission

Comment: hi, @Nick.McDermaid I mean hardcode in cloud function and deploy them in the server/firebase, the hacker can still access my server code to get my apikey?

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for hint, I checked this poor articles